# how to declare function in vb.net to call c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, dll, dllimport

I need to call a function located in a C++ dll from a VB.NET project.

The definition in C++ dll documentation is:

```cpp
HRESULT GetStatus(LPBYTE lpSize, LPBYTE lpStatus, HWND hWnd = 0)
```

`lpSize` Data: size of `lpStatus`
`lpStatus`: Specify a pointer of an area to store the Device Status.
The Status and following data are stored.
255 bytes of space is required to store data

I declare the function like this

```vb
<DllImport("cplusplusdll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="GetStatus")>
Public Function GetStatus(ByVal lpSize As String, ByRef lpStatus As String, ByVal hwnd As Long) As Integer
End Function
```

And I call it like this:

```vb
Dim status As String
result = GetStatus("255", status, 0)
```

but when I call, I get an error about pinvoikeStackImbalance, pinvoke signature not match... seems the definition is not ok...

I've tried lot of combinations but without success. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LPBYTE` is a pointer to a `BYTE`, so those are `IntPtr()` and marshal it (`Marshal.Copy()`). Do you know the size?

Comment: If `LPBYTE` is indeed meant to represent an `LPSTR`, like it can be understood from your usage, and if the second argument is supposed to *receive* a string, then `GetStatus(ByVal lpSize As String, ByVal lpStatus As StringBuilder, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer`. I seriously doubt though that the first argument, which looks like the size of the buffer, is a string. If it is indeed an `LPBYTE` to begin with, then it could be that you are supposed to pass a pointer to int rather than to its string representation.

Comment: i've updated the post with info about the function information

Comment: jimi, thanks for your reply. the size is 255

Comment: There is not enough information. What is the first argument supposed to point to, an integer of some sort or indeed a string buffer? Does the function return the actual length via the first argument, and if so, how - as an integer within the buffer or as a textual representation in the buffer? If 255 bytes are required, why have the first argument in the first place?

Comment: @GSerg, then, what is the right definition and how to call the function? thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`LPBYTE` would normally be declared `ByVal lpSize As Byte()` so:

```vb
Public Function GetStatus(ByVal lpSize As Byte(), ByRef lpStatus As Byte(), ByVal hwnd As Long) As Integer
```

Check the C++ function is actually StdCall, it may be CDecl.

---

*EDIT*
Looking at the small amount of info you provided, I very much doubt that `lpSize` is declared `LPBYTE`, as it represents the length of the array given in `lpStatus`. Also, `hWnd` should be an `IntPtr`

Here, it appears you are trying to receive a string in the space provided for in `lpStatus`. We can do this with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, but an easier method using `StringBuilder` is available. Do **NOT** use `String` for this:

```vb
<DllImport("cplusplusdll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, _
CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="GetStatus")>
    Public Function GetStatus(ByVal lpSize As Integer, <Out> ByVal lpStatus As StringBuilder, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
```

`````vb
Dim status As New StringBuilder(255)
result = GetStatus(status.Length, status, 0)
```

We can also get the `HRESULT` marshaled directly to an exception, if you would like:
````vb
<DllImport("cplusplusdll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, _
CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="GetStatus", _
PreserveSig = False)>
    Public Sub GetStatus(ByVal lpSize As Integer, <Out> ByVal lpStatus As StringBuilder, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)
    End Sub
`````

Comment: i have declared like you told. but how to call it? how to set the variables and call the function?

Comment: There is no indication from the definition that you can pass a `string`, do you know that is possible? It's just a byte array

Comment: can you tell me how to call from vb.net the function GetStatus with your modified definition?

Comment: `GetStatus(mybytearray1, mybytearray2, 0)` It is possible to pass a string in certain circumstances, without seeing the documentation for the function I have no idea. You may also need custom marshaling

Comment: thanks. how to set value to mybytearray1?

Comment: No idea, I don't know what info lpSize and lpStatus represent, so I don't know what you are supposed to pass. Where do you get `"255", status` from? Is there documentation for this function, I'm not familiar with it from Win32?

Comment: with this, i continue getting error: Dim lpsize() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("255")
        Dim status(255) As Byte
       result = GetStatus(lpsize, status, 0)

Comment: i've just added info bout lpSize and lpStatus. I forgot on post start. Sorry

Comment: Have update to reflect what I think you need

Comment: ok, the error has solved. thanks! but status is always empty :-(

Comment: Not sure, maybe remove `<Out>`? Do you have the actual docs for this function?

Comment: how to use the `HRESULT` marshaled directly to an exception, please? what means this?

Comment: We use `PreserveSig = True` for this. This means that the `HRESULT` (which is an exception code) will be checked by the .NET marshaler, and if it does not equal `S_OK` then it will throw a `COMException`. This means we don't need to check the result ourselves for errors, we can rely on an error being thrown, and the function can be declared `Sub` with no return value. I **strongly** suggest you post a link to the docs for this function if you have one.

Comment: i would like to show the docs, but that is a confidential document and i can not publish it. :-(

Comment: Can you [edit] in a full excerpt of the docs just for this function? We need to see how it is meant to be used? Anonymize it if necessary

Comment: im looking the code of the status is returned in HRESULT... i dont understand then the purpose of the lpStatus... ¿?

Comment: `lpStatus` seems to be a buffer to store the result from the function. You call `GetStatus` with a `StringBuilder` buffer, tell it the size of the buffer, and it returns the value inside the buffer. Are you getting a non-zero `HRESULT` returned?

Comment: HRESULT is allways a non-zero code. as the status changes, HRESULT reflects the new status code correctly, but lpStatus is always empty...

Comment: That could be the case that it is actually a result, but normally HRESULT is just an error code if there is, otherwise 0 (`S_OK`). What is the HRESULT, are you getting a different one every time?

Comment: by the way, im exactly in the same situation with this other function. HRESULT GetVersion(LPBYTE lpVersion, HWND hWnd = 0 ). i use this declare and i get the same error than in the GetStatus! <DllImport("dll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="GetVersion")>
    Public Function GetVersion(<Out> ByVal lpVersion As StringBuilder, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

Comment: about HRESULT, as im getting always an error code, status is empty. once i get HRESULT with 0 (no error) surely i will have data in status. Thanks very much!

Comment: **What is the return result, the error code?** Or I can't help you

Comment: I think all is ok. the erro codes i receive are from the dll status. that is all is running ok.

Comment: can you please take a look a this post? i'm applying exactly same solution but doesn't works... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754427/how-to-declare-vb-net-to-call-a-function-inside-a-c-dll

Comment: ok, now, with all running ok i must receive data in status. but im getting an error telling "invalid input parameter". i think this can be about the spStatus variable...

Comment: You may need to add 1 to the size, because of the null character terminator `status.Length + 1`

Comment: same result with size at 256

Comment: Only in chat and you need 20 reputation for that. Wait, let's get a moderator...